# what font family support on mobile browser

Tags: mobile-website

I am developing a website top work properly on mobile browser. i am trying for different font family but whatever i m selecting looks is seems to same.I am testing my website on

http://mobiready.com/. What font family is supported by mobile browser. I am looking for narrow font style.;
Thanks

Comment: What kind of fonts are you after? Generally the best ones to stick to are simple and common ones, like Times New Roman or Arial. Are you looking for any "fancy" font? If you're trying to use it for something like a logo, try saving it as an image.

Comment: 1) font-family: arial narrow;  2) font-family: verdana; 3) font-family: time new roman;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one [Fonts](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html)

Answer (score -1):

we can use font family called ROBOTO for smart phones . They are like Roboto light, medium ,Roboto condensed bold and Regular.